# Compare dates using GEQ or LSS

Tags: batch-file, windows-scripting

See this script which am currently testing

```
:DateQuery
set MigrationDate=01,09,2016
echo DateFormat=%date%
echo dd = %date:~0,2%
echo mm = %date:~3,2%
echo yyyy = %date:~6,4%
Set CurrentDate=%date:~0,2%,%date:~3,2%,%date:~6,4%
for /f "tokens=1,2,3 delims=," %%a in ("%MigrationDate%") do set "d2=%%a%%b%%c"
for /f "tokens=1,2,3 delims=," %%a in ("%CurrentDate%") do set "d1=%%a%%b%%c"
echo %d2%,%d1% >C:\temp\Date.txt
goto:Checks

:Checks
if %d2% GTR %d1% echo %d2%,%d1% Greater Than >C:\temp\gtr.txt
if %d2% LSS %d1% echo %d2%,%d1% less >C:\temp\lss.txt
if %d2% EQU %d1% echo %d2%,%d1% equal >C:\temp\equ.txt
```

Trouble is I am using the 01,09,2016 as the migration date to deploy a particular file....but in testing it sees 01/09/2016 as a lesser date than for example today 18,08,2016

I used the example test file and it just outputs to the LSS with

01092016 (is less than) 18082016

Obviously this is incorrect, can you please help?

Thanks

Mikoyan

Comment: Batch files have no concept of what the variable type is.  In order to accurately compare dates you would need to put the dates in a YYYYMMDD format.

Comment: Wow thanks, this looks like its working better. Will test further but cheers!

Comment: Well, I think that 01092016 is _obviously_ less than 18082016; about 16 times lesser, indeed...

Comment: @Aacini 16.5 to be exact.

Comment: What would be the best method then to compare the date...using the method im using its comparing numerically in which Aacini is correct. Any ideas :s

Comment: Just put the dates in YYYYMMDD order as @Squashman suggested. For example: `20160831` is less than `20160901`, `20161231` is less than `20170101`, etc...

Comment: Thanks again for this guys, will test further with the dates in reverse